# Markdown to HTML w/ syntax highlighting using Gulp

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, markdown

I'm using the [gulp-markdown](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-markdown) package to render a markdown file into an HTML partial. (It uses the npm [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) package for the actual rendering.) Everything renders fine, except for my code blocks!! How do I get gulp to put out correctly formatted HTML?

Here is my gulp:

```
var gulp      = require('gulp');
var markdown  = require('gulp-markdown');
markdown.marked.setOptions({
  renderer: new markdown.marked.Renderer(),
  gfm: true,
  tables: true,
  breaks: false,
  pedantic: false,
  sanitize: true,
  smartLists: true,
  smartypants: false
});

// turn md files into html partials
gulp.task('blogPosts', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/blog/blogOne.md')
        .pipe(markdown())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/partials'));
});
```

And here is my markdown:

````
```JavaScript
app.controller('DisplayController', ['$scope', 'ClogsService', function($scope, ClogsService){
  $scope.clogs = [];
  $scope.getClogs = function() {
    ClogService.getClogs()
      .then(function(response){
        ClogsService.clogs = response.data;
          $scope.clogs = ClogsService.clogs;
      });
    };
})
```
````

Here is the output HTML:

```
<pre><code>app.controller(&#39;DisplayController&#39;, [&#39;$scope&#39;, &#39;ClogsService&#39;, function($scope, ClogsService){
  $scope.clogs = [];
  $scope.getClogs = function() {
    ClogService.getClogs()
      .then(function(response){
        ClogsService.clogs = response.data;
          $scope.clogs = ClogsService.clogs;
      });
    };
})
</code></pre>
```

My page renders like this: [image]

How do I get the page to render code blocks correctly with syntax highlighting?

Comment: Looks like you need to provide a `highlight` function: https://github.com/chjj/marked#options-1

Comment: Thanks. Tried using that, but I still don't get syntax highlighting. I think there is a more basic step I am missing